# secret in firebase function is "undefined"

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have to admit, I'm a new in Firebase Functions

So I need some help, cause I didn't find any solution in the tutorial

I want to store some API_KEY in Firebase Functions and retrieve it

So this is my `index.ts` of functions

```js
import { onRequest } from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import * as logger from 'firebase-functions/logger';

export const getApiKey = onRequest(
  { secrets: ['API_KEY'] },
  (request, response) => {
    logger.log(process.env.API_KEY);
    response.json({ key: process.env.API_KEY });
  },
);
```

```
app.component.ts
```

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { httpsCallable, Functions } from '@angular/fire/functions';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent {
  data$: any;
  constructor(private funcs: Functions) {
    const callable = httpsCallable(funcs, 'getApiKey');
    this.data$ = callable({});
  }
}
```

In `app.module` I use emulators

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// Firebase
import { initializeApp, provideFirebaseApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { provideAuth, getAuth, connectAuthEmulator } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import {
  provideFirestore,
  getFirestore,
  connectFirestoreEmulator,
} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import {
  provideFunctions,
  getFunctions,
  connectFunctionsEmulator,
} from '@angular/fire/functions';
import {
  provideStorage,
  getStorage,
  connectStorageEmulator,
} from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://127.0.0.1:9099', {
          disableWarnings: true,
        });
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      const firestore = getFirestore();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, '127.0.0.1', 8080);
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
    provideStorage(() => {
      const storage = getStorage();
      if (location.hostname === 'localhost') {
        connectStorageEmulator(storage, '127.0.0.1', 5001);
      }
      return storage;
    }),
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [HomeComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I also run this command
`firebase functions:secrets:set API_KEY`

In console I see this error

```js
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): FirebaseError: Response is missing data field.
FirebaseError: Response is missing data field.
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:1193:31)
    at zone.js:1264:17
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:402:31)
    at core.mjs:25998:55
    at AsyncStackTaggingZoneSpec.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:25998:36)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.mjs:26308:33)
    at _ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:401:60)
    at Zone.runTask (zone.js:173:47)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:581:35)
```

and in terminal I see

```js
  functions: Beginning execution of "us-central1-getApiKey"
>  {"severity":"INFO","message":"undefined"}
```

Probably I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what exactly